# Show bootstrap table only after filtering results using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a basic filter functionality to search a Bootstrap 4 table as per W3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_filters.asp).

This works fine but I would like to hide the table and just show the results when the filter search is performed.

i.e. Webpage shows a Search Field only - typing something reveals relevant rows of the table only.

I do not yet know JavaScript very well.
I have found this from a previous questions (thanks Evan Carroll!):

```
<div id="myId" class="d-none">Foobar</div>

$("#myId").removeClass('d-none');
```

This seems to make sense but I don't know how to combine this javascript with the existing code below - where do I put it?

Current javascript filter code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchinput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#mainsearch tr").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the table inside the div and can update the logic like below..

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssilas777/tpcvora7/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchinput").on("keyup", function() {
   $("#myId").addClass('d-none');
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(value != ''){
    $("#mainsearch tr").filter(function() {
    $("#myId").removeClass('d-none');
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Worked perfectly - thanks for the quick response.